# Rolling Harmonic mean with R (number of n days)

Tags: r

I want to get the harmonic mean of n days

For example

a <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15)

```
assuming month end is `3, 6, 9 ,12`

If n = 2, i want to get the harmonic mean of 

1,2,3,4,5 (t-2~ t+2 with midpoint 3)
4,5,6,7,8 (t-2~ t+2 with midpoint 6) and so on

if n = 1 it would be
harmonic mean of 2,3,4 for month-end :3
```

I have the daily returns as xts. All i want to do is get the harmonic mean of n days. Thanks

Comment: I struggle to understand what you're trying to do. You give a numeric `vector` `a <- 1:15` and then talk about month ends. What is `n`? What do you mean by `t-2~ t+2`? Since you mention a rolling (harmonic) mean, what is your window width? Can you provide your expected output for the sample vector `a`?

Comment: thanks for your answer and sorry for my lack of ability in asking questions..lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you're trying to do. I assume you want to calculate a rolling harmonic mean with a fixed window width `n`; to do so we can use `zoo::rollapplyr`

```
n <- 5
rollapplyr(a, width = n, FUN = function(x) 1 / mean(1 / x), fill = NA)
#[1]        NA        NA        NA        NA  2.189781  3.448276  4.575163
#[8]  5.652759  6.705695  7.744315  8.773818  9.797130 10.816035 11.831685
#[15] 12.844861
```